# To get same cityId of selected cityName in spinner

Tags: android

i parsed json data ( cityName and cityId) , want to show only city name in spinner, but on spinner item selected, the selected city name as well as city id  must go on next activity using intent... I am unable to get same cityId of selected cityName in spinner.

please any suggestion with example ... thanks

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: i want to send city name and city id to next activity, but when i am selecting parsed city name in spinner i am not geting correct city id

Comment: glad to help you happy coding

Comment: **Thanks** @AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Checkout [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-populating-spinner-json-tutorial/) tutorial and try that way it will help you :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<String> worldlist;
    ArrayList<WorldPopulation> world;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Download JSON file AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();

    }

    // Download JSON file AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Locate the WorldPopulation Class 
            world = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
            // Create an array to populate the spinner 
            worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            // JSON file URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt");

            try {
                // Locate the NodeList name
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();

                    worldpop.setRank(jsonobject.optString("rank"));
                    worldpop.setCountry(jsonobject.optString("country"));
                    worldpop.setPopulation(jsonobject.optString("population"));
                    worldpop.setFlag(jsonobject.optString("flag"));
                    world.add(worldpop);

                    // Populate spinner with country names
                    worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("country"));

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
            Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

            // Spinner adapter
            mySpinner
                    .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                            worldlist));

            // Spinner on item click listener
            mySpinner
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                            TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
                            TextView txtcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
                            TextView txtpopulation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.population);

                            // Set the text followed by the position 
                            txtrank.setText("Rank : "
                                    + world.get(position).getRank());
                            txtcountry.setText("Country : "
                                    + world.get(position).getCountry());
                            txtpopulation.setText("Population : "
                                    + world.get(position).getPopulation());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i think this would surely help me , i will try your answer for my code and let you know asap.. thanks brother